# Behaviour of solution of $Ax=c$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a system of $n$ linear equations $Ax=c$, $a_{ii}>0$, $a_{ij}<0$ for $j\neq i$ and $A$ is diagonally dominant. Is it true that $dx_i/dc_i>0$?

Comment: If it helps at all, the question is equivalent to asking if the diagonal entries of $A^{-1}$ are positive.